# Groovy execute shell script and capture output

Tags: groovy

I need to set an environment variable from a Groovy script, the value of the `env` var should be produced with the AWS CLI, my command

```
def proc ='aws codeartifact get-authorization-token --region=eu-central-1 --domain companyname --domain-owner accountnumber --query authorizationToken --output text'.execute()
env.CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN = proc.in.text
```

But I get an error message

```
10:59:47  Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "aws": error=2, No such file or directory
```

I am new to Groovy and looking around for solutions, any tips in the meanwhile?

Comment: What is your operating system? AWS CLI version?

Answer (score 0):

Your path variable maybe wrong. Check it by

```
println System.getenv('PATH')
```

then fix it.

Comment: its already in the path, if i ssh to the host and try running `aws` commands it works